# Does SoapUI support PKI/certificate authentication?

Tags: certificate, soapui

**Does SoapUI support PKI authentication?** I currently have version SoapUI 5.0.0 available to me.
If so then...

- What versions support it?
- Are any of the versions free?
- How do I configure the tool to use PKI?

If anyone can, please assist with details or a link to another forum posting that I cannot find.

All authentication done to the server is done via certificate. I can use HttpRequester plugin with Firefox but find it to be lacking and want to use SoapUI. In order to do so I need to have SoapUI present my cert to the server but cannot find information on how this is done.

Additionally, to be more precise I have .p12 and a .ppk file to work with. What do I need to do to get this to function? I posted this to the SmartBear forum site almost a week ago but have not gotten any response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to this is (when using SoapUI 5.0.0)
File > Preferences
Click SSL Settings tab
KeyStore: C:\pathToYour\fileName.p12
KeyStore Password: password to your p12 file
Click OK

Comment: Might be useful for others: v4.5.0 has a bug and cannot read .pfx's, yet and old v3.0.1 works fine.